# Google App Engine Enterprise and SQL/Django Admin?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, admin

I'm having a difficult time finding definitive information on this. If I have a paid, enterprise account with Google, can I host SQL databases and thus the Django Admin feature? I have a MySQL database I would like to port to GAE and make viewable via the Django Admin section, and an Enterprise Google account is an option, but I need to know for sure if I can even do this with an Enterprise account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [App Engine For Business Roadmap](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/business/roadmap.html) list the status of hosted SQL as *Preview*, with an ETA in Q2 2011. So I guess the answer is:

Not yet.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, however, deeper in the documentation it seems to indicate that it's already there. I was wondering if there was perhaps a beta version available or something. I guess not.